# .useDefaultAccount() for GoogleApiClient not working properly

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to initialize the History API from Google Play services. Now ever since we updated our app, the `.useDefaultAccount()` method is not working properly and the connection result fails. This will cause a login prompt to appear in our app, where the user needs the choose their account. We would like to prevent this. Is there a way to do that?

How we make the client object and connect it (inside an `AsyncTask`):

```
GoogleApiClient apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                    .useDefaultAccount()
                    .build();
            ConnectionResult connectionResult = apiClient.blockingConnect();

            if (!connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
                if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && context instanceof Activity) {
                    try {
                        connectionResult.startResolutionForResult((Activity) context, 1);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Utter Failure
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google API Client should be [built on the `onCreate`](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#start_an_automatically_managed_connection) method of the Activity, not inside the AsyncTask. Try to move the code block to the appropriate class. This may be the reason as to why you're getting the `SendIntentException`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are handling the account choice result correctly in onActivityResult(). If you have not connected to GoogleApiClient there, the dialog will keep showing up.